# Home and End keys on Windows keyboard don't work on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I've plugged a basic UK Windows keyboard into my MacBook. I keep hitting `Home` & `End` but they don't work as I expect, they jump to the top/bottom of the document/page rather than the start/end of the line. It's very annoying since I am doing this automatically as I type!

Is there a way to make them work as I expect, i.e. why don't they map to CMD+LEFT/RIGHT?

Answer (score 1):

Create ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and save this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfLine:;
    "\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfLine:;
    "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:;
    "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:;
}
```

See [TextMate Blog » Key bindings for switchers](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/). `pageUp:` and `pageDown:` don't work in Safari, Chrome, or iWork applications.

It doesn't work in all applications or text views though. Another option would be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

[image]

You can customize the setting by copying it from [here](https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml) and adding it to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).